# Apply YADCF on Datatable column based on column class

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable, datatables, yadcf

I am creating a system which makes significant use of DataTables and I would like to add support for YADCF as well, because well it is fantastic.

I have set up my site so that the DataTable is initiated by a script help on my layout page set to trigger on discovery of a particular class.  As a consequence the script knows little about the table as they are varied and different within the site, an example is shown below.

This is the table.

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover dataTable-example-noorder">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.CaseName)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.NotifiedDate)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.LossRef)
        </th>
        <th class="ddl">
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.SpecificBond.EnablingBond.UnderwritingPeriod)
        </th>
        <th class="ddl">
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.PractitionerId)
        </th>
        <th class="ddl">
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.SuccessorPractitionerId)
        </th>
        <th class="ddl">
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Status)
        </th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @cHelpers.Link(item)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.NotifiedDate)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.LossRef)
            </td>
            <td>
                @if(item.SpecificBond != null)
                {
                    if(item.SpecificBond.EnablingBond!= null)
                    {
                        @cHelpers.Link(item.SpecificBond.EnablingBond.UnderwritingPeriod)    
                    }
                }
            </td>
            <td>
                @cHelpers.Link(item.Practitioner)
            </td>
            <td>
                @cHelpers.Link(item.SuccessorPractitioner)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Status)
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
</tbody>
```

And then this is the script which initiates the DataTable instance

```
function FormatDataTables() {
$('.dataTable-example, .dataTable-example-noorder').DataTable({
    order: [],
    pageLength: 25,
    dom: '<"html5buttons"B>lTfgitp',
    buttons: [
        { extend: 'copy' },
        { extend: 'csv' },
        { extend: 'excel', title: 'Export' },
        { extend: 'pdf', title: 'Export' },

        {
            extend: 'print',
            customize: function (win) {
                $(win.document.body).addClass('white-bg');
                $(win.document.body).css('font-size', '10px');

                $(win.document.body).find('table')
                        .addClass('compact')
                        .css('font-size', 'inherit');
            }
        }

    ],
    "stateSave": true,
    "stateDuration": 0,
    "footerCallback": function ( row, data, start, end, display ) {
        var api = this.api(), data;
        var formatter = new Intl.NumberFormat('en-UK', {
            style: 'currency',
            currency: 'GBP',
            minimumFractionDigits: 0,
        });
        // Remove the formatting to get integer data for summation
        var intVal = function ( i ) {
            return typeof i === 'string' ?
                i.replace(/[\£,]/g, '')*1 :
                typeof i === 'number' ?
                i : 0;
        };
        //iterate through each column
        api.columns().indexes().flatten().each(function (i) {
            var column = api.column(i);
            var drop = column.nodes()
            //if the column is one which requested a ddl then add it
            var h = column.header();
            var s = $(h).attr("class");
            if (s.includes('total-col')) {
                // Total over all pages
                total = api
                    .column( i )
                    .data()
                    .reduce( function (a, b) {
                        return intVal(a) + intVal(b);
                    }, 0 );

                // Total over this page
                pageTotal = api
                    .column( i, { page: 'current'} )
                    .data()
                    .reduce( function (a, b) {
                        return intVal(a) + intVal(b);
                    }, 0 );

                // Update footer
                if (pageTotal != total) {
                    $(api.column(i).footer()).html(formatter.format(pageTotal) + '<br /> Total - ' + formatter.format(total) + '');
                }
                else {
                    $(api.column(i).footer()).html(formatter.format(pageTotal));
                }
            };
        });
    },
    initComplete: function () {
        var api = this.api();
        //iterate through each column
        api.columns().indexes().flatten().each(function (i) {
            var column = api.column(i);
            var drop = column.nodes()
            //if the column is one which requested a ddl then add it
            var h = column.header();
            var s = $(h).attr("class");
            if (s.includes('hidden-col')) {
                column.visible(false);
            }
            if (s.includes('ddl')) {
                var select = $('<select><option value=""></option></select>')
                .appendTo($(column.header()))
                .on('change', function () {
                    var val = $.fn.dataTable.util.escapeRegex(
                        $(this).val()
                    );
                    column
                        .search(val ? '^' + val + '$' : '', true, false)
                        .draw();
                });
                column.data().unique().sort().each(function (d, j) {
                    //handle hyperlinks
                    var t = d.substring(d.indexOf('>') + 1, d.lastIndexOf('<'))
                    if (t == '') {
                        select.append('<option value="' + d + '">' + d + '</option>')
                    }
                    else {
                        select.append('<option value="' + t + '">' + t + '</option>')
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }
});

}
```

This works fine but whereas at the moment I am manually creating the dropdowns using the column.each part of the datatables api to iterate through the columns looking for a class 'ddl' in the heading.

What I would like to do is replace this part;

```
if (s.includes('ddl')) {
                var select = $('<select><option value=""></option></select>')
                .appendTo($(column.header()))
                .on('change', function () {
                    var val = $.fn.dataTable.util.escapeRegex(
                        $(this).val()
                    );
                    column
                        .search(val ? '^' + val + '$' : '', true, false)
                        .draw();
                });
                column.data().unique().sort().each(function (d, j) {
                    //handle hyperlinks
                    var t = d.substring(d.indexOf('>') + 1, d.lastIndexOf('<'))
                    if (t == '') {
                        select.append('<option value="' + d + '">' + d + '</option>')
                    }
                    else {
                        select.append('<option value="' + t + '">' + t + '</option>')
                    }
                });
            }
```

With YADCF as it adds a great deal more functionality. However, I am struggling to find away of declaring the columns I want ordered and keep the flexibility in deployment I am currently enjoying.

Conscious that I may not have described what I am after there is a fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/Syrowe/7tran0k5/

Is there a way I can match my current deployment strategy and deploy YADCF?

Any suggestions on how this might be a achieved properly, or advice on why what I am trying to do is a travesty of design welcome.

Thanks

sy

Comment: Im not sure what the problem is, you are trying to reset the filter but it doesn't work ?

Comment: @Daniel thanks for coming back.  I have added some more detail on what I am doing which hopefully makes it clearer.  It is the initiation of YADCF that is challenging me